# How to detect that user is going to be authenticated? (before authenticate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I need to trigger callback before Devise redirects user to login page, probably because `authenticate_user!` method detected he's not logged in. Something like:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :edit

def not_authenticated_callback
  # do something
end
```

It shouldn't be called if `authenticate_user!` has not been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an ugly solution:

```
around_filter :intersect_warden

def intersect_warden
  success = false
  result = catch(:warden) do
    result = yield
    success = true
    result
  end

  unless success
    not_authenticated_callback
    throw(:warden, result)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

while using **before_filter: authenticate_user!** ,the action will not go inside your controller, if the user not logged in.

if you use before_filter,
You cant access any functions inside your controller, when the user not logged in.

Comment: before_filter is executed in the context of controller.

Comment: i think it calls a helper method thats defined in lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb
Here the 'authenticate#{resource_name}!' is evaluated to "authenticate_user!"

Comment: not sure though how u can check if the user is authenticated or not. u can add a after_filter for authenticate_user! where u can check if user has been signed in or not.

Comment: after filter is not executed if user is not authenticated